# Can I have a dynamic host policty with autocert?

Tags: go, lets-encrypt

I am looking at some sample code for using autocert with a go web server.

Would it be possible for the hostPolicy implementation to by dynamic i.e. read the while listed hosts from the database (as they will change constantly).

```
m := autocert.Manager{
        Cache:      certcache,
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        HostPolicy: hostPolicy,
    }
```

What would a skeleton structure look for a custom hostPolicy implementation?

https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/acme/autocert/autocert.go#L60

Is has to return a function?

Answer (score 2):

> Does it have to return a function?

yes, this is part of the signature of the [autocert.Manager](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/acme/autocert/autocert.go#L92) struct.

The [Manager.HostPolicy](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/acme/autocert/autocert.go#L120) field is of type [autocert.HostPolicy](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/acme/autocert/autocert.go#L60), which is, indeed, a function of type `func(ctx context.Context, host string) error`.

> What would a skeleton structure look for a custom hostPolicy implementation?

You simply set a custom function for the HostPolicy field to implement the logic to query the database.

```
m := autocert.Manager{
    // ... more fields here
    HostPolicy: func(ctx context.Context, host string) error{
        // implement database calls here
        return nil 
    },
}
```

As per the doc, you should return an error to reject an host.